# Harness for soft-bodied animal

Tags: anatomy, domestication, tools

There is a soft-bodied animal approximately 1m in length. It has a worm-like body with a hydrostatic skeleton, and several pairs of legs that function as muscular hydrostats. Its anatomy has a rather average amount of flexibility/dexterity and strength for what it is

How could such an animal be harnessed to let it pull loads without killing it or making it unable to walk. The technology level is roughly medieval

Comment: Do you have technological constraints regarding the harness, or can it be up to what we know of science?

Comment: What is it trying to haul, 1 1meter hydrostatic animal is not generating much force.

Comment: Assuming it can't fully retract the legs, then it wouldn't be able to slip out of a tight-fitting one-piece bodysuit with holes for each leg. That would make a good harness. Though, this seems like a terrible choice for a draft animal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Corset**

Let's consider Newton's third law. If the soft body is tough enough to withstand the friction against the ground necessary for cartage, then it's tough enough for the harness. This would suggest that "soft body" is irrelevant to the question (I'll get back to this) and only the body shape is important. Even with that simplification, it's a nasty basset-hound of a question. Corsets are used on the human body to hold up dresses, but they usually require a waist and hip bones to work. However, that's not always the case. Some women are so slender that it's literally the friction of the corset that keeps the skirt from pulling everything down.

All that being said, we're back to Newton. If the worm's body will permit the friction on the road to haul the cart, then it will permit the same friction on the body via a corset harness.

Whether or not that works is a matter of either narrative necessity or the OP's desire to create a creature with a physiology that would work. The specific physiology of a worm, scaled to the size of, say, a horse, would collapse under its own weight.

Therefore I'll conclude with a [frame challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609). The "soft bodied" creature really isn't. It must have musculature and either a bone structure or a cartilage structure that will hold its shape vs. its size and allow the muscle action to apply the necessary force to the road. I therefore contend that there's sufficient structure to the creature to allow a corset-style harness.

*And the irony of this answer is not lost on me.*

Comment: Octopus don't have a rigid structure that holds their shape. They have a shape but it is not rigid in the least.  https://youtu.be/e1nXu6ZkdqE?t=12

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica An octopus doesn't have to handle the same stuff that a large-bodied terrestrial animal has to. Big land animals need muscles, cartilage, etc, specially if they're to be used as work animals.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica And they're underwater....

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately the answer is probably surgical**

We can imagine piercing the integument in the same way that ears are pierced. To spread the load and prevent tearing, it might be necessary to sew or glue a number of small tough fabric patches at intervals.

A rigid harness will not allow free motion. If it is tight, the creature won't be able to move. If it is loose, the creature can simply wriggle out.

EDIT

As an afterthought, a full-body net or stocking that allows only the legs to protrude might work.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any limits to the creature's pliability? If there's a minimum width hole it can squeeze through, it would be fairly simple to lace a net around its front with a mesh size tighter than that, and with cords running from the edges of the net to a carriage or sled in the back of the animal. As it pushes itself forward, it would then push the net as well, which pulls on whatever its connected to.